# App runs out of memory  in iPAD 1 upgraded to iOS 5

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios4, ios5

I am still figuring out why my iPAD with iOS 5 runs out of memory and forces my app to quit.

The same app when i tried to run on iPAD with iOS 4 it runs for more than 1 hour though it crashed later on.

but when i tried to run the same app on iPAD with iOS 5 it crashes in 10-12 minutes.

When i checked the crash logs, I found all the crash were due to low memory.

I wanted to know that does iOS 5 uses more memory, due to which my iPAD 1 runs out of it.?

Comment: You should focus on why your app continues to increase in memory size, rather than what uses more memory in iOS 5.  Try using instruments to profile your application and find out where the problem is.

Comment: i tried everything-used instruments(though it also crashes sometimes) i know the memory is increasing but why it is so fast in iOS 5 or why it runs out of memory in iOS 5 so quickly but not on iOS 4..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have search the same problem on Apple community and found that this same problem persist with other developer also

It would be nice if the problem can be resolved with a patch provided by apple, however I think it has more to do with the memory spec's of the iPad1 vs. iPad2. Clearly IOS 5 isn't optimized for the 256MB of DDR ram that the iPad1 has.

Comment: In our case we are not even getting -didReceiveMemoryWarning callback. What is happening at your end? Figured out any reasons yet?

Comment: i was getting memory warning in both ios 4 and ios 5 but the effect of those memory warning was quicker in ios 5 with ipad1..I just reduced the memory warnings so the app is stable..

Comment: But in our case application crashes as soon as it is launched, and this happens only in iOS 5 + iPad 1. Do you think that the reason is same? Thanks!

Comment: As in iOS 5 there are some libraries that are deprecated..so in your case you are definitely using something which is not supported in iOS 5. I faced similar problem...debug through your code and try to find the exact line of code that is making it crash.